# MySQL table design for Grade with subject and sub-subjects

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have made 2 tables for Grades(grades_tbl) and Subject(subject_tbl) but I want to further make a sub-subject table for which I am confused. Following are the 2 tables

**grades_tbl**

```
grade_id - grade_name
=====================
10          Class 9
11          Class 10
```

**subject_tbl**

```
subject_id - subject_name  - grade_parent
=========================================
1             English          10
2             Maths            10
3             Science          11
```

Now I want **sub-subjects** for example **Mental Maths** which will come under maths. I thought of an idea as below:

```
subject_id - subject_name  - grade_parent - hasSubject
======================================================
1             English          10              0
2             Maths            10              1
3             Science          11              0
4             Mental Maths     2               0
```

I will check each subject, if hasSubject is 1 then it will loop again to find the grade_parent in **subject_tbl**. I don't know if this is a right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a separate table for your "sub-subjects". All you'd need is the `id` of the sub-subject, the `subject_id` from the subject table and the name of the sub-subject.

Then you can join across the two table to get which subjects have sub-subjects etc.

Comment: If in future I want further category then, I will have to make again a table for that ? Is there any other solution for this ?

Comment: Yes, if you want another category for a subject, for example "teacher", you'd have to create another table. This is the best solution, because a good database design will have tables for each thing you need, then relationships between the tables to join it all up.